# map function vs for loop puppeteer package in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

i´ve been trying puppetter package in nodejs, and when i use data function works pretty different in contrast to for loop

here is what im talking about:

map function

```
data.map(async(info) =>{
        let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(info.url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" })
        await page.screenshot({ path: info.src })

        
        await browser.close();

    })

    console.log("map function completed");
```

this is the input of the map function:

map function completed

**first screenshot saved**

**second screenshot saved**

For loop is working like this:

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
let page = await browser.newPage();

for (let i = 0; i<=data.length-1; i++) {
console.log(data[i].url);
await page.goto(data[i].url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" })
await page.screenshot({ path: data[i].src })

}
await browser.close();
console.log("for loop completed");
```

this is the input of the for loop:

**first screenshot saved**

**second screenshot saved**

for loop completed

Why is this happening? i thought they work in the same way. I would like if somebody explain why is this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make it work in the same way you have to change your first code in this way

```
const promises = data.map(async(info) =>{
        let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ ignoreHTTPSErrors: true });
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(info.url, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" })
        await page.screenshot({ path: info.src })

        
        await browser.close();

    })

await Promise.all(promises)
console.log("map function completed");
```

when you use `map` and `async` your items are transformed into promises and they will execute in parallel (in your case that's not true because your are using puppeteer) so you have to `await` that all of them are resolved to log the success message.

Your second code is more synchronous because it's all wrapper in the same function and every `await` are executed one after one

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, because you use an asynchronous function within the `map` function, the first synchronous `console.log()` function works. Because normally asynchronous operation works after synchronous operation.

In the second case, the`for loop`, top-level await, and the `console.log()` function work sequentially because they are synchronous.